# Consulta Linq group by

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Quiero construir una consulta linq aplicando group by pero tengo una clase extend en la cual tengo que igualar la clase de entidad con la clase extend.

```
IEnumerable<ModeloExtend> result = Context.Modelos
                                                .Where(x => x.LineaId == damas || x.LineaId == caballeros)
                                                .GroupBy(x => x.LineaId)
                                                .Select(g => new ModeloExtend
                                                {
                                                    ModeloExtendId = g.Key,
                                                    Descripcion = g.ElementAt()
                                                }).ToList();
```

No puedo hacer el selec new

Deseo hacer esto pero con GROUP BY elininando el ORDER BY

```
List<ModeloExtend> result = Context.Modelos
                .Where(x => x.LineaId == damas || x.LineaId == caballeros)
                .OrderBy(x => x.LineaId)
                .Select(x => new ModeloExtend
                {
                    ModeloExtendId = x.ModeloId,
                    Descripcion = x.Descripcion 
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el linq que defines solo estas definiendo propiedades simples de la entidad `Modelos` no aplica el GROUP BY, a lo sumo usarias el DISTINCT()

[[Linq] Distinct y GroupBy usando IEquatable<>](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2012/07/linq-distinct-y-groupby-usando.html)

de esta forma no apareceran duplicados de modelos

```
List<ModeloExtend> result = Context.Modelos
                .Where(x => x.LineaId == damas || x.LineaId == caballeros)
                .Select(x => new ModeloExtend
                {
                    ModeloExtendId = x.ModeloId,
                    Descripcion = x.Descripcion 
                }).Distinct().ToList();
```

recuerda implementar la interfaz `IEquatable<>` en la clase `ModeloExtend` para asi poder determinar cuando son duplicadas las entidades